# How do I get selected database name from Combo box in a text box when I choose the Path name

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I want to get the database name from Database Selection when I select the path in Database Backup... For E.g: I selected the name of database name 'Sample' and then I click Browse button and choose the Path where I want to backup... Now, I want the selected database name Sample after the Location... 
For Instance: C:\Users\Abc\Desktop\Sample...  Help to me to get the selected name of database in a text box.

Code for Browse button of Backup:

```
private void btnBrowseBa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if(dlg.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtLocBa.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's your drop down's name?

Comment: Also consider an extension like .bak for your backup file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
if(dlg.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
{
    var database = yourDatabaseComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    var extension= "bak";
    var databaseFileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", database, extension);
    txtLocBa.Text = System.IO.Path.Combine(dlg.SelectedPath, databaseFileName);
}
```

Comment: Your motto is now 'Geek Programmer'...  how you have become a geek Programmer??? I also want to be a geek programmer like you... One advice???

Comment: @Warda practice makes perfect :)

Comment: Well, I do...  Thanks again...:)

Comment: @Warda You are welcome, feel free to inform me when you need some help, I will help you if I can :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91247/discussion-between-warda-and-reza-aghaei).

Answer (score 0):

Try this which will get the path:

```
path = Path.Combine(backupPath, databaseNameComboBox.Text);
```

Comment: Can't OP just concatenate whatever is already selected in combobox?

Comment: @edrodriguez I think my edit crossed with your comment.

Comment: But it helped you didn't it? :^)

Comment: When using Path.Combine, you don't need to add \

Comment: Well glad we're on the same page @StuartL ;)

Comment: @edrodriguez If you are trying ti imply that I copied your answer, you are sorley incorrect.

Comment: @StuartL you know? it never crossed my mind... so i'd say the incorrect one here is you :^)

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending on what your combobox's name is:

```
private void btnBrowseBa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = "";
    FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if(dlg.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
    {
        path = Path.Combine(dlg.SelectedPath, comboBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you didn't include System.IO, you can also do: System.IO.Path.Combine

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate:

`txtLocBa.Text = dlg.SelectedPath + @"\" + comboBox1.Text`

Comment: probably missing the extension

Comment: and that's all that matters @Warda :) the extension can be concatenated as well FYI